# show calendar events in div on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

hello I'm new to the jquery I'm making events calendar I have done the calendar module.
when I click on the date it goes to events.php page and show the events for the day.
but I want to show events for the day in div tag same page call (index.php). when I click on the date link I'm passing query string to the events.php page and I get the events for the day so I need to pass query string to the events.php page and get events in the div tag withot going to the events.php page

this is my coding

```
<td bgcolor="green" style="color:#FFFFFF">
    <a href='events.php?id=<?php echo $actualDay;?>&year=<?php echo $cYear?>&month=<?php echo $cMonth?>'><?php echo($actualDay);?></a>
</td>
```

I want the link result to be displayed inside a div using jquery.

Comment: Anyway did you have a look at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If i've understood the question correctly.. you want to call the events.php on the same page with no redircts? Check jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**UPDATE**

doesnt need to be a form.. can be loaded onReady or only href link. whatever you like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//when you submit the form
$(".submitbutton").click(function() {  
var name = "bob";
  $.ajax({
    url:"events.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"name="+name+"&email=<?php echo $email; ?>"....... ,
    success:function(response){
      //work with the response from echo in events.php
      alert(response);
    }
  });

});

}); //end of (ready)
```

**EDIT**

*HTML*

```
<a href="#" id="yourid" class="link">the link</a>
```

*jQuery*

```
//catches all clicks with class link
$(".link").click(function() { 
     //the ajax function
```

Comment: in jquery put the php variable in php tags "name=<?php echo $actualDay; ?>" etc... p.s. use firebug in firefox to check the network messages and repsonses

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform an **AJAX request** to retrieve the data for a specific event and fill a **hidden div** with the data retrieved from the **call**.

In order to do the above, you have to create an **empty** , style it properly, and hide it. Then you need to create sort of a **request handler page**, which should contain the same logic as the events.php page but instead of displaying the details it will only return the data in either **[JSON](http://www.json.org/) or XML format**. This returned data will be be parsed using javascript\jquery on your calendar page and filled into your hidden div, which you will show when finish the procedure above.

You need to research the following and learn to use the following:

[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This is also a complete example of the above:

[Example](http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp)

It might be appropriate to your case.

Note: You might also need this:

[$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: how to make request handler page because calendar page by clicking the date it parse the query string to events.php page to get events for the day bye only making same logic as the events.php it doesn't get day of the events if I don't pass the query string from calendar page